# Problem with sending dynamic array in write system call in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, operating-system

I have created two processes using fork, I want to send an integer array on heap memory to child process using write and read system call. In the parent process, if i make the array on stack the problem is solved but i want to do it in heap.Below is my code:

```
int fd[2];

pipe(fd);

pid_t p=fork();

if(p>0){

close(fd[0]);

int *info=new int[7];

info[0]=1;
info[1]=2;
info[2]=3;
info[3]=3;
info[4]=4;
info[5]=5;
info[6]=6;



 write(fd[1],info,sizeof(info));

 close(fd[1]);

 delete info;
 wait(NULL);

 }

 else if(p==0){

 close(fd[1]);


 int *inf=new int[7];

 read(fd[0],inf,sizeof(inf));

 for(int i=0;i<7;i++){

 cout<<inf[i]<<endl;
 }

 close(fd[0]);
 }
```

The output of above code is:
1
2
0
0
0
0
0.
Can somebody tell me what my mistake is? If info array is on stack the problem is resolved but  have to create it on heap.

Comment: `sizeof(info)` -- What value do you think this will be?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie 7

Comment: Well, that's your mistake.  It isn't 7.

Comment: The point of the comment was really to see if you know what you're doing when you say `sizeof(info)`.  The `info` is a pointer, it knows nothing more than that.

Comment: i have solved it instead of sizeof(info) i have to write sizeof(info) *4, thanks for the help

Comment: No, that is not the solution, it is totally wrong.  See my answer.  The `write` function wants the total number of bytes to write, and `sizeof(int *) * 4` is not correct.

Comment: ok i understand now thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two mistakes in your code.

The first is this:

```
int *info=new int[7];
//..
write(fd[1],info,sizeof(info));
```

Since `info` is an `int *`, the `sizeof(info)` is the same as `sizeof(int *)`, the size of a pointer to integer.  Usually the value will be either 4 or 8.

To fix this, you want to state the total number of bytes to write, and that is `sizeof(int) * 7`.  You want to write 7 `int`-sized values, and that is computed by multipying 7 by `sizeof(int)`:

`write(fd[1],info, sizeof(int) * 7);`

Also you stated that it works with an array.  Note that *a pointer is not an array*, that's why you had different results when you used a true array instead of a pointer.

---

The second mistake is that you are using the wrong form of `delete`.  Since you are using `new[]`, you should use `delete[]`, not `delete`.